# Rancher/Vmware Persistent Folder Storage Path

Tags: vmware, datastore, rancher, persistent-storage, rancheros

I feel that I'm very close to getting this working. I have a small Rancher 2.2.8 cluster which I'm able to successfully deploy onto my vCenter 6.7. However, I forgot the first time around to set up the cloud provider so that I could have persistent storage.

I have been reading the documentation and have tried numerous vsphereCloudProvider setups but in no case can it find the folder when I try to create the persistent storage.

- Rancher: 2.2.8
- vCenter: 6.7 (onto an ESXi 6.5 host)
- CentOS 7

Here is an example of what I'm trying. I have tried absolute path as well and in all cases it can find the datastore, just not the folder:

```
cloud_provider:
  name: vsphere
  vsphereCloudProvider:
    global:
      insecure-flag: true
    virtual_center:
      www.vcenterserver.com:
        user: administrator@vsphere.local  
        password: blahblahblah
        datacenters: Datacenter
    workspace:
      server: www.vcenterserver.com:
      folder: rancher-pv-01
      datacenter: Datacenter
      default-datastore: SC02
    disk:
      scsicontrollertype: pvscsi
    network:
      public-network: DHCP
```

Sorry I forgot to include the actual error...

```
I0924 18:03:04.603132       1 event.go:209] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"vol-01", UID:"0cfbd0ec-def5-11e9-8275-005056b17f97", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7961", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "vcenter-storage-class": folder 'rancher-pv-01' not found
```